# Use parameter in format string

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, string-formatting

This:

```
print '{:x<4d}'.format(34)
```

prints this:

```
34xx
```

How can I do this:

```
width = 13
print '{:x<|width|d}'.format(34)
```

to get this:

```
34xxxxxxxxxxx
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put one format field inside of the other:

```
>>> width = 13
>>> print '{:x<{}d}'.format(34, width)
34xxxxxxxxxxx
>>>
```

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings):

> A `format_spec` field can also include nested replacement fields within
>   it. These nested replacement fields can contain only a field name;
>   conversion flags and format specifications are not allowed. The
>   replacement fields within the `format_spec` are substituted before the
>   `format_spec` string is interpreted. This allows the formatting of a
>   value to be dynamically specified.

Note however that the nesting can only go one level deep.

Comment: Thank you. Just what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

This works

```
('{:x<%dd}' % width).format(34)
```

Answer (score 1):

this will work:

```
>>> width = 13 
>>> print '{:x<{}d}'.format(34,width)
34xxxxxxxxxxx
```

Answer (score 1):

You can nest arguments in format, using kwargs allows you to be more explicit and less susceptible to confusing results:

```
fillchar = 'x'
width = 13
print "{:{f}<{w}d}".format(34, w=width, f=fillchar)
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks a lot. Using named params are really good here.